Windows 11: Opened zip file using "start" but address bar is blank
In Windows 10, when I double-click a zip-file or issue start filename.zip from CMD, Windows Explorer shows the files therein and the full path of the zip file appears in the address bar.  The navigation pane also shows my location in the folder tree.  If the parent folder contains many zip files, they all show up in the navigation pane and I can quickly move from one zip file to another by simply clicking them in succession.
In Windows 11, I only get the above behaviour from double-clicking the zip file -- not from issuing start filename.zip at a CMD prompt.  The latter yields an empty address bar and the navigation pane shows top-level folders -- not the folder representing the zip file.  This is far less helpful than the above behaviour that I saw in Windows 10.  Is there any way to get that behaviour from issuing start in Windows 11?
P.S. I initially described the problem wrongly as double-clicking filename.zip, then getting an empty address bar and a folder tree navigation pane that is not expanded down to the level of the zip file.  As can be seen in the comments, it is actually the Windows start command that is causing this in Windows 11.

I wasn’t able to reproduce the behavior you described on my Windows 10 box, I double click a .zip file, I am prompted to open (unzip) the file. What third-party applications do you have installed to handle .zip files?

have you extracted the zip file?

@Ramhound: I've used Windows 10 across many laptops, both corporate and personal.  I've always seen the behaviour that I described in the posted question without any 3rd party apps.  It seems very much like a native Windows Explorer feature, to be able to descending zip files as if they were folders.

I took another look, double clicking does indeed open the archive within File Explorer, but the address bar is not empty for me on Windows 11.

I think I may have a thread to follow in terms of troubleshooting.  I tried double-clicking in Windows 11 so that I could be 100% sure in responding to @Frank Thomas. What a surprise! I get the full path in the address bar. With further mussing about, I realized that I have always equated Cygwin's cygstart filename with double-clicking filename.  So cygstart seems to behave differently on my Windows 11 machine, and I'm unsure whether it is due to the version of the packages or just some inherent incompatibility with Windows 11.

I'm in the midst of streamlining Cygwin on the Windows 10 machine, but once done, I can compare the behaviour there with the Windows 11 machine.  On a separate debugging step, I noted that cygstart is just Cygwin's counterpart to Windows's start command, so I tried the following from a CMD shell: start filename.zip.  The resulting file browsing window also had an empty address bar, so I tracked it down to start. I'll have to compare with start on Windows 10 later because I need to get Cygwin working to issue chmod u+x filename.zip before start will work.

Just to confirm, the problem does indeed seem to boil down to the fact that start filename.zip behaves differently on my Windows 10 and Windows 11 machines.  I've updated the question to reflect this.
